# The type 'ValidationModelActionFilterAttribute' must derive from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.IFilterMetadata'.' IN asp.net core WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am creating a custom Filter for modelstate validation.
But I am getting the above error which i cannot figure it out.

**Startup.cs**

```
 services.AddMvc(opts => 
            {
                opts.Filters.Add(typeof(ValidationModelActionFilterAttribute));
            });
```

**ValidationModelActionFilterAttribute.cs**

```
public class ValidationModelActionFilterAttribute :ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public ValidationModelActionFilterAttribute()
        {

        }
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(new ValidationResultModel(context.ModelState));
            }
        }
    }
```

ValidationResultModel.cs

```
  public class ValidationResultModel
    {
        public string Message { get;  }
        public List<ValidationError> Errors { get; }

        public ValidationResultModel(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
        {
            Message = "Validation Failed";
            Errors = modelState.Keys.SelectMany(key => modelState[key].Errors.Select(x => new ValidationError(key, x.ErrorMessage))).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `IFilterMetadata` looks like an empty interface, can you just add it to your attribute?

Comment: tried it doesnot work

Comment: "does not work" in what way?

Comment: Same error as shown above

Comment: So your code is now `public class ValidationModelActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IFilterMetadata`?

Comment: Yes. I tried that it does not make much sense as ActionFilterAttribute already implements it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142666/discussion-between-maxspan-and-davidg).

Answer (score 0):

there are two versions of `ActionFilterAttribute`

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute`

`System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute`

make sure you are using correct one according to your project type and controller type

use first one if the project is aso.net core